# Get fixed number of records from different column of the same table

Tags: sql-server

I've a table with 4 columns: `Prctuid`, `Puid`, `PCode`, and `Code_Desc`

I need to select 10 records of each `Prctuid` for each `PCode`.

If there are 5 `Prcruid`s that contain 2 `Pcode`s and each `Pcode` has a number of `Puid`s, then the output should have 100 records.

Comment: What have you tried that's not working for you?  If you're getting an error, what is it?

Comment: Atleast first try yourself. Then ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number`

```
select 
   x.Prctuid
   ,x.Puid
   ,x.PCode
   ,x.Code_Desc
from 
(select 
   *,
   RN = row_number() over (partition by Prctuid, PCode order by PCode)
 from yourTable
) x
where x.RN <= 10
```

Comment: No problem @user9952388